Remove old point before drawing new one
In Netlogo, i have a dict that looks like this
{{table: [["random" {{array: 10 -477 436 -84 123}}] ["cooperate" {{array: 3 -322 398 -458 -409}}] ["defect" {{array: -6 -398 396 156 267}}] ["tit-for-tat" {{array: 10 -458 348 -478 -378}}] ["unforgiving" {{array: 45 -409 465 -378 -440}}]]}}

I want to plot it to something that looks like a histogram, but that cannot handle negative counts. I was thinking of plotting it like this:
plotxy 1 array:item (table:get outcomes-dict "random") 0

but the line or point does not go away when drawing another point. I tried most versions of clear-plot etc but I couldn't get anything useful from them.
Is there a way to do this in Netlogo. I am very flexible on the actual implementation.

You can't un-plot things, so to remove something you'll need to clear-plot and then re-plot everything you want to keep.

Where should I place the clear-plot, its deleting everthing
